# Adobe PDF Reader blocks my keys in Firefox

Tags: firefox, adobe-reader

When previewing a PDF in Firefox and clicking into the content of the PDF, I am not able to use keyboard combinations like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a new tab any more.

Is there any keyboard action to take focus away from Adobe Reader and return it to the browser?

Comment: I've noticed that the Flash plugin does this as well, and it's not been fixed for ages. Adobe's software being buggy is not a great surprise.

Comment: That's right! I also noticed that this is the behaviour for the integrated PDF reader in mozilla, I think it is by design because otherwise you will have no possibiliy to search via shurtcuts but there must exist a break out key combination!

Comment: I completely agree, a break-out key combo is a *must*, but in all these years Mozilla seems to have been unable to implement it.